# Which is the best way to transfer bulk of data (i.e. objects) from one Activity to another Activity in Android?

Tags: android, object, android-intent

What is the best way to transfer bulk of data (i.e. objects) from one *[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)* to another *Activity* in Android?

---

**Note**

Do `putextra` or `getextra` fulfill this thing? Because I have bulk of objects to transfer.

Comment: What kind of objects are you trying to send?  Simple string arrays, complex object, etc.?  There's a few possibilities, which include making your objects Parcelable, adding to a bundle, etc., but you'd need to provide what type of objects and maybe a code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your `Object`s into a `Serializable` and insert them into a `Bundle`, then attach the `Bundle` to your `Activity` and pass it through, retrieving it and unserializing it in the next `Activity`.

Comment: You can use Parcelable instead.. That would be better.

Comment: @RajaJawahar this question was asked in 2011... Parcelable didn't exist then ;)